# Incomplete tests when using Mockery

Tags: php, phpunit, mockery

Let's say I'm testing that a method calls another method in php

```
<?php
use \Mockery as m;

public function testMethodCallsOtherMethod {
    $m = m::Mock(new StdClass);
    $m->assertCalledWith('methodName')->once();
    doSomethingSoMCallsMethodName($m);
}

function tearDown() {
    m::close();
}
```

When I run this test with PHPUnit it reports the test is incomplete, because there's no PHPUnit assertion in the test. However it is a valid test and will error if the method is not called. Any good solutions for getting PHPUnit to realize this is a valid test?

Comment: There is maybe good reasons for PHPUnit to say that. Actually, you are testing nothing concrete here... You are just testing the implementation, what is the interest ? If you refactor your code, for example for readability, your test will break even if everything work well.

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround would be a dummy assertion:

```
$this->assertTrue(true);
```